# Sharepoint surveys. Can I generate a "failed to respond" notification?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've created a survey in SharePoint that 10 individuals are required to create a new response to on a daily basis. Is there a way to set up a workflow to notify me when 1 of the 10 people do NOT respond to the survey?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a site workflow using a `Call HTTP Web Service` action.  Then use a RESTful query to grab items from that list that were created `Today`.

I would create another list as well that would contain the names of the members that are supposed to respond.  Do another `Call HTTP Web Service` action to query back the names from that list.

With what items are returned in your REST queries, run a check to see if each name from your list is in a `Created By` field for an item in your survey.  If they are not, add their name to a variable.  At the end of your loop you should have a variable containing who has not submitted something for `Today`.

You could have this site workflow run on a timer job or have it use a `Pause` action and wait for a day and run it at the end of the day.